# Lattice Diamond command line tool doesn't know 'synthesis' command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, tcl, lattice-diamond

I have a (free) Lattice Diamond 3.7 installation on Windows 7 and I would like to run synthesis jobs from command line. I generated a *.prj file containing all relevant command line options, like part, toplevel and all source files.

Then I started `pnmainc.exe` from my PowerShell and executed: `synthesis -f arith_prng.prj`

```
-a "ECP5UM"
-top arith_prng
-logfile D:\git\PoC\temp\lattice\arith_prng.lse.log
-lib poc
-vhd D:/git/PoC/tb/common/my_project.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/tb/common/my_config_KC705.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/utils.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/config.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/math.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/strings.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/vectors.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/physical.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/common/components.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/arith/arith.pkg.vhdl
-vhd D:/git/PoC/src/arith/arith_prng.vhdl
```

The synthesis process started and finished. Next I tried to achieve the same behavior with a wrapping Python script, controlling STDIN and STDOUT of a subprocess.

I can execute some commands, but `synthesis` is reported as unknown command. It's not listed in help. I assume, that's because synthesis.exe is an external program.

For example, if I send `help`, then all help topics are displayed.

**What can I do to run Tcl commands for Diamond from Python?**

That's my Python code for experimenting on a Tcl-Shell wrapper.

```
from subprocess      import Popen    as Subprocess_Popen
from subprocess      import PIPE      as Subprocess_Pipe
from subprocess      import STDOUT    as Subprocess_StdOut

class Executable:
  _POC_BOUNDARY = "====== POC BOUNDARY ======"

  def __init__(self, executablePath):
    self._process =    None
    self._executablePath =    executablePath

  @property
  def Path(self):
    return self._executablePath

  def StartProcess(self, parameterList):
    parameterList.insert(0, str(self._executablePath))
    self._process = Subprocess_Popen(parameterList, stdin=Subprocess_Pipe, stdout=Subprocess_Pipe, stderr=Subprocess_StdOut, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=16, shell=True)

  def Send(self, line):
    print("  sending command: {0}".format(line))
    self._process.stdin.write(line + "\n")
    self._process.stdin.flush()

  def SendBoundary(self):
    print("  sending boundary")
    self.Send("puts \"{0}\"\n".format(self._POC_BOUNDARY))

  def GetReader(self):
    for line in iter(self._process.stdout.readline, ""):
      yield line[:-1]

tclShell = Executable(r"D:\Lattice\diamond\3.7_x64\bin\nt64\pnmainc.exe")
print("starting process: {0!s}".format(tclShell.Path))
tclShell.StartProcess([])
reader = tclShell.GetReader()
iterator = iter(reader)

# send boundary and wait until pnmainc.exe is ready
tclShell.SendBoundary()
for line in iterator:
  print(line)
  if (line == tclShell._POC_BOUNDARY):
    break
print("pnmainc.exe is ready...")

tclShell.Send("help")
tclShell.SendBoundary()
for line in iterator:
  print(line)
  if (line == tclShell._POC_BOUNDARY):
    break
print("pnmainc.exe is ready...")

tclShell.Send("synthesis -f arith_prng.prj")
tclShell.SendBoundary()
for line in iterator:
  print(line)
  if (line == tclShell._POC_BOUNDARY):
    break
print("pnmainc.exe is ready...")

print("exit program")
tclShell.Send("exit")
print("reading output")
for line in iterator:
  print(line)

print("done")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a synthesis, there is no need for TCL scripting with `pnmainc`. You can directly run the synthesizer binary as follows.

#### Windows

The `synthesises.exe` must be run from a command shell with all necessary Lattice environment variables. The environment is setup by an executable called `pnwrap.exe` in the `bin/nt64` directory. In your example, this executable must be called as follows from a shell:

```
D:\Lattice\diamond\3.7_x64\bin\nt64\pnwrap.exe -exec D:\Lattice\diamond\3.7_x64\ispfpga\bin\nt64\synthesis.exe -f arith_prng.prj
```

The `-exec` parameter specifies the executable to run in the Lattice environment. All following arguments are passed to `synthesis.exe`.

From within Python, you can run the synthesizer with (using your `Executable` class):

```py
exe = Executable(r"D:\Lattice\diamond\3.7_x64\bin\nt64\pnwrap.exe")
parameterList = ['-exec', r"D:\Lattice\diamond\3.7_x64\ispfpga\bin\nt64\synthesis.exe", '-f', 'arith_prng']
exe.StartProcess(parameterList)
```

Unfortunately, `pnwrap.exe` opens a new command shell window to setup the environment. Thus, the output cannot be redirected via a pipe. But, the log will also be found in the log-file specified in the `.prj` file.

#### Linux

At first, you will have to load the Lattice Diamond environment to setup all necessary environment variables. With Bash syntax, this will be:

```
bindir=/opt/lattice/diamond/3.7_x64/bin/lin64
source $bindir/diamond_env
```

Then, you can directly execute `synthesis` from the `ispfpga/bin/lin64` directory with a command line as in your example:

```
synthesis -f arith_prng.prj
```

The `synthesis` executable will be found in `$PATH`.

From within Python, you can run the synthesizer with (using your `Executable` class):

```py
exe = Executable('/opt/lattice/diamond/3.7_x64/ispfpga/bin/lin64/synthesis')
parameterList = ['-f', 'arith_prng']
exe.StartProcess(parameterList)
```